# I want to create a package in SSIS to copy all the file names from folder to excel file

Tags: ssis

I want to create a package in SSIS to copy all the file names from 1 folder to excel file?

Comment: Good for you. But what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

> Create a dataflow task
>
> Open the dataflow task and add a script component as a source
>
> Open the script transformation editor
>
> Add an output column, ex DT_WSTR with size of 255
>
> Loop through your folder and fetch the filenames
>
> Add the filename to the output column you just created
>
> Close the script transformation editor
>
> Add an excel destination
>
> Connect the script compnent to the excel destination
>
> Add a connection to the excel file you want to store the filenames in
>
> Set the mapping accordingly to store your filename values to the file
>   column

Something like that...

You can test it in BIDS GUI, run it by using dtexec or add it as a job to the sql agent